# Audio/Video File storage in cordova/phonegap application folder rather than phone gallery

Tags: javascript, android, cordova-3

I am developing android application using Javascript, HTML and phonegap/cordova. In application I want to record video/audio and store it in my application folder rather than storing in gallery. Currently my recorded videos are saved in gallery. I have heard that fileSystem api of phonegap is considered dead from April 2014. Can anyone suggest some different way?